# @LastModifiedDate causes additional update in database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, auditing

It is kind of strange, but when @LastModifiedDate annotation is used on my entity, it fires additional update on saving new object.
If I set @EnableJpaAuditing(modifyOnCreate = false), then it is only insert, but last modified date is not set while saving new entity.

Is there a way to make it set last modified date while inserting, without firing extra update to database or am i missing something?

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return () -> System.getProperty("user.name", "undefined");
    }
}
```

Abstract entity with getters (working with getters as i am using them elsewhere for Hibernate):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractGenericJson extends GenericJson {

    private DateTime createdDate;
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate;
    private String createdBy;
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "audit_create_ts", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    @Convert(converter = JodaDateTimeConverter.class)
    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "audit_update_ts")
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Convert(converter = JodaDateTimeConverter.class)
    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "audit_user_tx", updatable = false)
    @CreatedBy
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "audit_upd_user_tx")
    @LastModifiedBy
    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }
...
```

Entity class

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class ConsumerInteraction extends AbstractGenericJson {
    private UUID uuid;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    public UUID getId() {
        return uuid;
    }
...
```

Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface InteractionRepo extends JpaRepository<ConsumerInteraction, UUID>{}
```

My test:

```
@SpringBootTest(
        properties = {
                "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC",
                "logging.level.org.springframework.data.auditing=DEBUG"
        })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import(JpaConfig.class)
public class InteractionRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    InteractionRepo dao;

    @Test
    public void testInsertSingle() {
        ConsumerInteraction i = new ConsumerInteraction();
        i.setCustomId(290050);

        i = dao.save(i);
        dao.flush();
    ...
```

And the log, which shows two Touched events, one for null uuid and then one more after uuid generated, which as i understand is the cause of subsequent update as no other fields have been modified.

```
2018/05/06 00:36:01 DEBUG | main | o.s.d.a.AuditingHandler:161 - Touched ConsumerInteraction{uuid=null, id=290050} - Last modification at java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1525563361086,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=18,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_YEAR=126,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=36,SECOND=1,MILLISECOND=86,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000] by xxx 
2018/05/06 00:36:05 DEBUG | main | o.s.d.a.AuditingHandler:161 - Touched ConsumerInteraction{uuid=4e38645b-aa13-435d-8416-4bb3792a2482, id=290050} - Last modification at java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1525563365716,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=18,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_YEAR=126,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=36,SECOND=5,MILLISECOND=716,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000] by xxx 
Hibernate: insert into tInteraction (audit_user_tx, audit_create_ts, audit_upd_user_tx, audit_update_ts, average_value, company_names, consumer, contract_id, id, description, desk, duration, ext_party_id, include_in_vote, interaction_date, interaction_id, interaction_type, interaction_value, override_value, party_name, payer_allocation_name, regions, sectors, sell_side_contacts, status, updated_by, updated_date, user_comment, user_rating, period_id, region, uuid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
Hibernate: update tInteraction set audit_upd_user_tx=?, audit_update_ts=?, average_value=?, company_names=?, consumer=?, contract_id=?, description=?, desk=?, duration=?, ext_party_id=?, include_in_vote=?, interaction_date=?, interaction_id=?, interaction_type=?, interaction_value=?, override_value=?, party_name=?, payer_allocation_name=?, regions=?, sectors=?, sell_side_contacts=?, status=?, updated_by=?, updated_date=?, user_comment=?, user_rating=? where uuid=?
```

Using Spring Boot jpa 1.5.12 and Hibernate 5.2.16.Final.

Sorry for long post, but I am about to give up on using @LastModifiedDate. Thanks!

Comment: If you think this is a bug then you should report this here https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJPA/issues/DATAJPA-1338?filter=allopenissues

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue with default TimeZone. Apparently, lastmodifieddate seems to be set in the local timezone, whereas I am using UTC for the Hibernate.  While debugging, i noted that lastModifiedDate is always rendering my entity dirty because timestamp's timezones don't match.

Updated base class to use java.util.Date for the timestamps and removed converter from Joda DateTime, it appears the problem is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with the implementation of the Converter. It is a known strange situation that has to do with dirty checking of Hibernate. Check [this article](https://medium.com/@paul.klingelhuber/hibernate-dirty-checking-with-converted-attributes-1b6d1cd27f68).