# Spring JPA Dont Save If No Fields Modified

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

In Spring JPA, I did not find anything about saving entity only if there are modification to the fields

After I get the record from JPA, how can I verify, before I save the entity, if there are modification/changes to the fields.
This is my approach

In the `hasModifications` function I can compare if `obj.field!=cloneObject.field` then only save

```
Class obj = repository.findById(id);
Class cloneObj = cloneObject(obj);
process(obj);
    if (hasModifications(obj,cloneObj))
       repository.save(obj);
     else
       //don't save
```

I tried adding `@DynamicUpdate` annotation at the class level. But it didnt work. Is there any other clean way to do this?

**EDIT** :
I am asking this as I have a field called last_updated_at in MySql DB. And Whenever I call save this field is getting updated with the current timestamp but no other fields values are updated.
So thats why I asked this question
Here is the table definition

```
'CREATE TABLE `username` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `info` mediumtext,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `version` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_updated_at` (`updated_at`),
  KEY `idx_created_at` (`created_at`)
)
```

**EDIT 2**:
I tried putting `@Trasactional` at the method and removed clone and save call. But still updated_at is getting updated in DB

```
@Transactional
public someMethod(){
Class obj = repository.findById(id);
process(obj);
}
```

Here is my obj entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gratification_entity_task")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class GratificationEntityTask {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TaskStatus status;
    @Convert(converter = InfoConverter.class)
    private Info info;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    private int retryCount;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BeneficiaryType beneficiaryType;
    private String beneficiaryId;
    @Convert(converter = GratificationConvertor.class)
    private GratificationData primaryGratification;
    @Convert(converter = GratificationScheduleConverter.class)
    private GratificationSchedule scheduleGratification;
    private String referenceId;
    private String redemptionType;
    private String clientId;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public TaskStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(TaskStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Info getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public long getExpiryTimestamp() {
        if (scheduleGratification != null && scheduleGratification.getExpiryTimestamp() > 0) {
            return scheduleGratification.getExpiryTimestamp();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public long getScheduleInSecondsInMillis() {
        if (scheduleGratification != null && scheduleGratification.getScheduleInSecs() > 0) {
            return scheduleGratification.getScheduleInSecs() * 1000;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void setInfo(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public int getRetryCount() {
        return retryCount;
    }

    public void setRetryCount(int retryCount) {
        this.retryCount = retryCount;
    }

    public BeneficiaryType getBeneficiaryType() {
        return beneficiaryType;
    }

    public void setBeneficiaryType(BeneficiaryType beneficiaryType) {
        this.beneficiaryType = beneficiaryType;
    }

    public String getBeneficiaryId() {
        return beneficiaryId;
    }

    public void setBeneficiaryId(String beneficiaryId) {
        this.beneficiaryId = beneficiaryId;
    }

    public GratificationData getPrimaryGratification() {
        return primaryGratification;
    }

    public void setPrimaryGratification(GratificationData primaryGratification) {
        this.primaryGratification = primaryGratification;
    }

    public GratificationSchedule getScheduleGratification() {
        return scheduleGratification;
    }

    public void setScheduleGratification(GratificationSchedule scheduleGratification) {
        this.scheduleGratification = scheduleGratification;
    }

    public String getReferenceId() {
        return referenceId;
    }

    public void setReferenceId(String referenceId) {
        this.referenceId = referenceId;
    }

    public String getRedemptionType() {
        return redemptionType;
    }

    public void setRedemptionType(String redemptionType) {
        this.redemptionType = redemptionType;
    }

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GratificationEntityTask{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", status=" + status +
                ", info=" + info +
                ", createdAt=" + createdAt +
                ", updatedAt=" + updatedAt +
                ", version=" + version +
                ", retryCount=" + retryCount +
                ", beneficiaryType=" + beneficiaryType +
                ", beneficiaryId='" + beneficiaryId + '\'' +
                ", primaryGratification=" + primaryGratification +
                ", scheduleGratification=" + scheduleGratification +
                ", referenceId='" + referenceId + '\'' +
                ", redemptionType='" + redemptionType + '\'' +
                ", clientId=" + clientId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't and don't need to, Hibernate already does this.

Comment: But I have a column in Db called last_updated_at. So Basically any update on the record update this timestamp. But there is no change in the record and this column is getting updated with the current time whenever I call save

Comment: Hibernate shouldn't issue an `UPDATE` query if nothing has changed. It will do dirty checking and based on that will determine if it needs to update. I'm assuming everything you do runs in a single transactions so the `findById` and `save` are executed in a single transaction? If not that would explain things.

Comment: How to check that actually if it is being run in a single transaction? Is it whether Transactional annotation has been put at the class level or the method level. If it is that case then no Transactional annotation has been put

Comment: If there is an `@Transactional` on the enclosing method. If not it doesn't run in a single tx, next to that make sure that it is called from outside the service else the `@Transactional` doesn't work. Finally, you don't need an explicit call to `save` if everything runs in a single transaction.

Comment: So  no `@Transactional` has been put on the enclosing method.What do u mean by outside the service?

Comment: And there is your problem. Add the annotation else it will always do an update as it cannot determine if things have changed. For that it needs an active session and transaction. So add that annotation. Outside the service litteraly as I state it. From outside the service so from one service to another and not a call to this method from inside this same service.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have put it at the method,but its not working. But that method is being called by another service. So do I need to put it at that method of a service.

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question, something is preventing Hibernate from doing its checks. Hibernate does the dirty checks and you shouldn't do it (Nor clone the thing) make sure you just do find/modify and save (but that isn't needed if everything is in a transactional method).

Comment: Actually my main use case is to not update the record when there are no fields modified. Because if I put `@Transactional` and remove the save method, then also the updated_at timestamp is getting updated although the other field values are same.

Comment: I understand your usecase and that should be how hibernate works. Did you only place `@Transactional` but still clone etc? Please add the code as you have now, as it now is unclear to me what you have.

Comment: What does your `process` method do and what does your entity look like.

Comment: Actually it only gets the values from the entity and does some processing of other objects. I am sure there is no setting of the field happening through the setter. Only getters are being called. There was one setter but I removed it.

Comment: Please show the code. Pretty sure or being certain are different things, another thing is that you have to make sure you have a proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementation (see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: Actaully many services are interlinked. This method is calling method of another service so cant put the code exactly.  One thing I can say that the repository is being used in other places as a dependency in other interlinked services but any function like save or findById is not being called. Is that may be the case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue which was causing the unnecessary update. While debugging I found the update query generated with Info column as one of the one columns set.

```
update
    com.paytm.gratification.commons.entity.GratificationEntityTask */ update
      gratification_entity_task 
    set
      info=?,
      updated_at=?,
      version=? 
    where
      id=? 
      and version=?
```

There was `@Convert` annotation at the entity level which was creating a new Object and causing a dirty read.
Here is the link which mentions this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181716/6780814

Answer (score 0):

Spring won't don anything here. This is all dealt with by JPA. You don't need to do anything here. The JPA provider will determine by itself whether an entity is modified and therefore an update needs to be issued.

Also explicitly saving the entity is not required. Once it was retrieved from the repository it is managed by the entity manager. From that point on all changes to the entity are tracked and will be synchronized to the database once a database flush is triggered (like when the transaction completes).

So the only code you need is:

```
SomeEntity obj = repository.findById(id);
process(obj);
```

which must be executed in a transaction (like in `@Transactional` method).

Comment: I have put it at the method where it is doing that but its not working. Do I need to put `@Transactional` from the method of the service which is calling this method?
BTW both these methods of two different services are public

Comment: Having a `@Transactional` annotated method higher up the call stack is perfectly fine. You can set a breakpoint at `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation)` to verify the annotation takes effect while debugging. You can also use `jakarta.persistence.EntityManager.contains(Object)` to check whether the entity at hand is actaully managed after it has been returned from the repo. Otherwise it's difficult to say what's wrong with your application without more details.

Comment: Actually my main use case is to not update the record when there are no fields modified. Because if I put @Transactional and remove the save method, then also the updated_at timestamp is getting updated although the other field values are same.

Comment: If you use a `@PreUpdate` annotated callback to set the `modified_at` this should only be invoked when the entity is actually modified as far as I understand and from my past experiences. But I have no definitive answer from the spec at hand.

Comment: I have used `@LastModifiedDate` in the modified column and `@AuditingEntityListener` at the entity level.You can see my EDIT 2. Is it the cause of it?

Comment: I'm not sure what spring is exactly doing in the auditing. You can try to set a breakpoint in `org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markModified(T)` to see when and why the modification date is set.